# Is there any OED-as-directed-graph research?

Tags: english, reference-request, lexicography

Say, I want to know what a "dog" is, so I read the definition for dog in the OED. But, of course, it contains a list of words too so I set out to read the definitions for those as well. This forms a directed graph. Was there any research done on this? I presume, for example, you won't need to understand what a "ventriloquist" is just to understand "dog" -- but , for example, is there a list of words that eventually the definition chains of all words reach?

Comment: Possibly better asked on Linguistics.SE.

Comment: I suppose someone may have done something like this. However, as you have specified it, there are enormous problems. For example, how will you avoid circularity?

Comment: Google Wordnet and Framenet.

Comment: it's easy to avoid circularity if you keep a list of words visited

Comment: @chx - You haven't thought this through. If you merely stop when you find a previously-visited word, you will end up with a very lopsided tree that is entirely dependent on the order of the definitions and the words contained within them. I suggest it will give you almost zero useful information. Why do you want to do this? What do you hope to gain from it?  If you can give a reason then a sensible answer might be possible.

Comment: I'm looking for the "core" or "fundamental" English words.

Comment: You'd probably find that all definitions are ultimately circular.  If you think about it, it's rather amazing how infants make the connection that *things have names*.  There have been cases of people who didn't make this connection until adulthood, and only then began to acquire language as we know it.

Comment: Sure there will be circles but I presume that each word will eventually cover a real lot of words and I wonder which one will be covered by all.

Comment: Dictionaries are pretty much guaranteed to be circular in their definitions. Attempts at establishing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_primes have worked at a distance from dictionary definitions.